# How to use transaction with two databases together?

Tags: php, mysql, database, transactions, yii2

There are two databases: DB1, DB2.
And these databases have on the table: DB1.groups [id, name] and DB2.keywords [id, name, group_id].
DB1.groups.id - it is a foreign key for DB2.keywords.group_id

The task is: get the data -> Process the data-> Update DB1.groups -> update DB2.keywords.
The pseudocode implementation:

```
//begin transaction for DB1;
begin_transaction('db1');
try {
    $a = get_data()
    $a = handle1($a);
    insert_to_db1($a);
    insert_to_db2($a); // here the query gets stuck and throws an error  “Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction” 
    commit_transaction('db1');
} catche(\Exception $e) {
    rollback_transaction('db1');
}
```

The reason is that I blocked the row in DB1 and updating the table in the second database DB2, it freezes because I have it in the foreign key of locked record DB1 (request it waits unlock row in the DB1). If I will remove the foreign key - everything is done quickly.

How to solve this problem? I understand that transactions are atomic for a single database, but I have a little problem to be atomic to the same database. I need use transaction for two databases together.
I don`t want remove foreign keys to solved this problem. 
I am scared to use this without transaction (I will have big problem when update only one DB).

How to solved problem?

Comment: You need to use one database connection.

Comment: @Vatev How can I use one  database connection for two databases?

Comment: Either run `USE <db name>` to switch databases, or use `<db name>.<table name>` in your queries.

Comment: I think the only way to do it is to know group_id before starting any of transactions. Otherwise your db2 trans won't see changes in db1 until you commit db1 trans